# What does lint_maintainer_format mean?

Tags: application-development

In a review for my click package, I saw the following message:

```
lint_maintainer_format
```

What does it mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the manifest, you need to specify your name and email address in the following form:

```
"maintainer": "Joe Bloggs <joe.bloggs@isp.com>"
```